# Draw coordinates in Google map using Cordova

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have developed the application in Ionic1. I need to draw the routes in Google map. The main objective is to draw the routes in Google map and Show the Marker. The marker is changed dynamically but routes persist same on map.

Sample Routes Coordinate's are

```
var ROUTE_POINTS = [
 {lat: 41.79883, lng: 140.75675},
  ...
 {lat: 41.79883, lng: 140.75673}
 ]
```

**Set the Marker**

```
 var latitude = data[0]['latitude'];
            var longitude = data[0]['longitude'];
            var options = { timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true };

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            var mapOptions = {
                center: latLng,
                zoom: 16,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

            //Wait until the map is loaded
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {

                previousMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    icon: $scope.baseurl + "/uploads/images/bus2.png",
                    position: latLng
                });
                // var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                //   content: latLng
                //  });
                google.maps.event.addListener(previousMarker, 'click', function () {
                    infoWindow.open(map, previousMarker);
                });

            });
```

I want to draw the multiple routes in Google map.

Comment: This is not related to codrova. You should change the tags to refer to google maps specifically. More chance of someone answering the question.

Comment: @somerandomusername  sure